# How to defer Maven test goal after deployment?

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

I'm using the JBoss and WildFly Maven plugin to deploy my applications.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The problem that I have found is that if I have some Junit test in my project they are executed **before** application deployment, leading to a test with an inconsistent application state. Is it possible to configure somehow this plugin to kick-in before the test phase ? 
Thanks

Comment: Why would it lead to an inconsistent application state? Running the tests should be independent from deploying the application. Something sounds fishy with your setup :-) Also, it's usually a best practice to run the tests *before* deploying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin by default executes alongside the `package` phase and you'll probably have issues attempting to run the plugin before your application is packaged. As an alternative, you could override the maven-surefire-plugin to run your tests in a later phase, such as `integration-test`, which would be executed after your application has been packaged.

Answer (score 1):

A practical example can be found on this [Maven tutorial](http://www.itbuzzpress.com/various/top-10-maven-issues-for-java-developers.html)  where it's show how to include failsafe plugin and bind it to the executions of the integration-test and verify phase. This way tests which are engineered as integration test (e.g ending in *IT) will execute only during the integration-test phase.